# docker-compose persistent data on host and container

Tags: docker, copy, containers, persistence, docker-compose

I have a problem with volumes in docker-compose yml 3.0+

So I know that a volume behaves like a mount.. But I have set up a wiki and when i set a volume in the docker-compose, the data on the container will be removed (hidden)

So how can I save data from my container to my host first and the next time I start the container, it will just overrides the data I saved.

So the current situation is:
I start with "docker-compose up --build" and a volume is created (empty) and will be copied to the container.. Everything in that folder on the container is deleted as a result

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  doku-wiki:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '4000:80'
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
COPY dokuwiki-stable /var/www/html/
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you looking for a way to "copy existing container data to a volume on container start"?

Comment: Yes, the first time i start the container via docker-compose up it should copy the existing container data to a volume. After that the container should use the date from the volume without overwriting everything.

For example I want to backup the folder "/data/pages/"

But on the first start the backup volume will be empty.. and it will copy nothing to /data/pages/ but deletes the existing content of the container

Comment: I do not see any volume definition in your docker-compose.yml file. Where does the volume come into play?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are using a host volume where you map a host directory into the container. When you do this, anything at that location inside your image will not be visible, only the files as they exist on the host.

If you want to have a copy of the files from inside your image to initialize the volume, you have two options:

1. Switched to a named volume. Docker will automatically initialize these to the contents of the image, including any permissions. If you don't require direct access to the files from outside of docker, this is the preferred solution.
2. Change your image entrypoint and the location where you store your files in the image.

On the second option, if you want /data to be a volume for your application, you could have an entrypoint.sh that does:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -d "/data" ]; then
  ln -s /data_save /data
elif [ -z "$(ls -A /data)" ]; then
  cp -a /data_save/. /data/
fi
exec "$@"
```

Your image would need to save all the initial files to /data_save instead of /data. Then if the directory is empty it would do a copy of /data_save to your volume /data. If the volume wasn't mapped at all, then it just creates a symlink from /data to /data_save. The last line runs the `CMD` from your Dockerfile or `docker run` cli as if the entrypoint wasn't ever there. The added lines to your Dockerfile would look like:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried the entrypoint.sh script but I get the following error when starting the container with docker-compose

"doku-wiki_1  | standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory""

Comment: Do I need any volumes for that second solution?

Comment: "no such file or directory" means either the file didn't get copied into the image, or the first line points to something that doesn't exist (`/bin/sh`) on your container. I've also seen that with windows linefeeds in the script. The second solution works with your current host volumes.

Comment: Just added my docker-compose and dockerfile to that topic. 

Step 3/6 : COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a33d89753408
Step 4/6 : RUN chmod 777 /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ada6d8df380d
Step 5/6 : ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 645f6e69f994
Creating development_doku-wiki_1
Attaching to development_doku-wiki_1
development_doku-wiki_1 exited with code 0

I changed the line ending to "LF" for the script. I dont get the error now anymore but the container will exit. Thanks again for your time and help.. I think Im very close...

Comment: Since you're using the php:7.1-apache base image, that has an entrypoint already and you'll need to call their entrypoint from yours. The last line in the script should read `exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"`

Comment: Ah that makes sense but still getting that "development_doku-wiki_1 exited with code 0" error after adding `exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"`

Comment: The second example above assumes you'd copy your files to /data_save inside your Dockerfile, and mounted a volume at /data. Did you update this for /var/www/html, did you update your Dockerfile for /var/www/html_save (or some other directory), and do you have a volume mounted at /var/www/html?

Comment: I will try that out and will tell you then.. did not change anything there yet

Comment: Mh somehow I cant get it to work.

I have my data, which I want to backup in "/var/www/html/"
And I have tried some combinations in my dockerfile and docker-compose.yml but I think Im still doing something wrong