# Docker volume files not propagating

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi I have been trying to make my following docker(based on moodle) compose file work

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: "mysql/mysql-server"
    container_name: moodle-db
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
       - ./moodle-db:/var/lib/mysql:z
  apache:
    image: my-moodle-image:latest
    container_name: moodle
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
       - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
       - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./moodledata:/var/www/moodledata:z
     #- ./themes:/var/www/theme
```

And it works as long as the commented line remains like that. 
/var/www/theme has some files, but when mounting the folders goes empty instead of propagaiting the files to the file system.

can anyone point out, the why?
Thanks in advance

Tringing to base myself of https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/#good-use-cases-for-tmpfs-mounts, in the following text:

**If the container’s image contains data at the mount point, this data will be propagated into the bind mount or volume.**

Comment: What linux distribution and version are you running? Do you have SELinux enabled? Are the files you're expecting on the host folder or inside your image?

Comment: Fedora server 26, already tried disabling selinux, the files are in the container and i am expecting them to be copied to the host when i mount the volume

Comment: Those docs are incorrect, bind mounts do not copy data from the image to the host. Perhaps this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575883/596285

Comment: Use named volumes if you use docker-compose file version '3' or higher or, due to your docker-compose version file is '2', you can change your commented line by `volumes_from: service_name`.