# Mount an empty folder in host to a non-empty folder in Docker

Tags: docker

The tool I'm using is delivered in a Docker image. Since installing the tool is extremely complicated with a bunch of dependencies, I want to work on the host with my IDE, but run it on the container.

So after download and load the image, I run:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /home/myself/WIP/thetool:/home/thetool name/label
```

Without mounting, the tool is located under `/home/thetool`, but with mounting, this folder is empty (since the folder in the host is empty).

Do I need to copy the tool from the container, then mount it, or there is a way to do it directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575883/596285

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can actually make that work with a docker volume with explicit device mount point.

If the directory **/home/myself/WIP/thetool** is empty, do the following:

**Create a docker volume as such:**

---

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=none \
    --opt device=/home/myself/WIP/thetool \
    --opt o=bind \
    tool_vol
```

---

**Start the container and mount the created volume:**

```
sudo docker run -it -v tool_vol:/home/thetool name/label
```

Now the data that is in `/home/thetool` inside the container will be available inside `/home/myself/WIP/thetool` even though the host folder was initially empty.

Comment: Nice use of a named volume with bind mounts, +1. Note that this only works when the directory is empty, once there's a file inside, or contents from the last instance of the container, docker won't initialize it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this behaves like a normal volume. If the volume already exists it will be mounted otherwise it will be created with content of the container's mount point.

Answer (score 11):

Docker-compose for yamenk great answer would be:

```
version: '2'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
services:
  your_service:
    volumes:
      - tool_vol:/home/thetool
    build: .
    command: your_command
volumes:
  tool_vol:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/myself/WIP/thetool
      o: bind
```

Answer (score 4):

You're going against the grain for this, host volumes are designed to inject files from the host into the container and let you manage the files from outside of the container.

You can copy your tool out of the container as part of your container's entrypoint, but you'll need to mount your volume in a different location from where you have the directory inside the container so that you have both the source and target directories available. A sample entrypoint for this looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -d "/data" ]; then
  ln -s /data_save /data
elif [ -z "$(ls -A /data)" ]; then
  cp -a /data_save/. /data/
fi
exec "$@"
```

And then the Dockerfile for that image would copy in and configure that entrypoint with:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```